# WARNING: Although PyQt5 is already imported, the PyQt5 backend could not be used

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt5

After installing Ubuntu 22.04 and trying to resurrect a [FlatCam](http://flatcam.org) build, I ran into this bizarre PyQt5 error:

> WARNING: Although PyQt5 is already imported, the PyQt5 backend could not
> be used ("cannot import name 'QtOpenGL' from 'PyQt5' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/**init**.py)").
> Note that running multiple GUI toolkits simultaneously can cause side effects.

pyopengl is already installed so I'm not sure what dependency is missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem magically resolved itself after installing pyqtgraph. After inspecting the dependent packages, I now believe the missing import was python3-pyqt5.qtopengl

Comment: Did you try to import anything Qt-related (including flatcam) *before* importing PyQt? If that's the case, that's the reason.

Comment: Ah, makes sense, that probably did occur